# check if tag exists in wp database

Tags: taxonomy

I have to display a button that links to a tag, but I have to hide the button if tag doesn't exists to avoid broken links.

How can I check if a specific tag exists inside wp database?

**This is what I have so far:**

```
    $tag_path = '/tag/testing/';
     if( !$page = get_page_by_path( $tag_path ) ){ 
    //hide button link
    } else {
   //show button link
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`term_exists`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) function.

Example Code:

```
<?php
$term = term_exists('tag1', 'post_tag');
if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
  echo "'tag1' post_tag exists!";
} else {
    echo "'tag1' post_tag does not exist!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check `has_tag`

```
if(has_tag('tag_name')) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Ref - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/